# How to import part of in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, import, built-value

I'm using built_value, I have created a class that has part

```
part 'custom_value.g.dart';
    
    abstract class CustomValue implements Built<CustomValue, CustomValueBuilder> {...some code}
```

it's the generated class with part of:

```
part of 'custom_value.dart';

class _$CustomValue extends CustomValue {...some code}
```

and now in the class where I have imported "import './custom_value.dart';" CustomValue it doesn't see the inheriting object _$CustomValue

error message:

> Undefined name '_$CustomValue'. Try correcting the name to one that is
> defined, or defining the name.

can it be solved somehow? i need this class for serialization

Comment: basically you are trying to extend your abstract class?

Comment: What you have should be working.  It's hard to tell what might be wrong without a reproducible example.

Comment: https://github.com/Vanethos/flutter-built-value-custom-deserializer/tree/master/lib/models As you can see, there are two model dart files. And there in custom_value.dart are two classes: CustomDataSerializer  and CustomValue, and what i want is extract CustomDataSerializer  to  another file, but then it doesnt see _$CustomValue from custom_value.g.dart